# how to get value of url parameter with colon in text in django

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have the following url:

http://mysite.com/config/1:1/

This gives me a 404 page not found.

If I try this:  it find my url entry no problem.
http://mysite.com/config/1/

This what my url pattern looks like:

```
 url(r'^config/(?P<config_id>\d+)/$', views.config, name='config'),
```

Is there a problem with having the colon in the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression allows only digits.  `\d` doesn't match `:`.  If your view function is able to handle the colon, broaden the pattern:

```
url(r'^config/(?P<config_id>[\d:]+)/$', views.config, name='config')
```

Since you've named the pattern `config_id` I suspect it's a primary key, and this will not work with the view, but that depends on the view itself.

Comment: Peter is correct, just make sure you refine the suggested pattern (if for example you don't want urls like "/config/1::23:/" to work) in order to avoid unnecessary requests (or 500s for that matter!).

Comment: Right - the regexp should accept input according to what your view is expecting, and nothing else.